# Apache Ignite Jdbc connection for 2 separate data grid on single machine

Tags: java, jdbc, ignite

I'm trying to setup on my machine the following ignite environment:

dev ingnite:

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder finder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
finder.setAddresses(Lists.newArrayList("127.0.0.1"));
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi.setIpFinder(finder));
cfg.setGridName("dev");
Ignite dev = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

test ingnite:

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder finder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
finder.setAddresses(Lists.newArrayList("127.0.0.1"));
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi.setIpFinder(finder));
cfg.setGridName("test");
Ignite test = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

The only difference in the configuration is the grid name ('dev' vs 'test'). Both of ignites are running as separate java proccess (e.g. java -jar... vs. mvn test). And now I want to establish jdbc connection for each data grid.

```
Class.forName(IgniteJdbcDriver.class.getName());
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite://localhost/" + cacheName);
```

But I can't to find any option to define grid name in the connection url. Can somebody help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved it with Connector Port

```
dev_cfg.getConnectorConfiguration().setPort(11211);
test_cfg.getConnectorConfiguration().setPort(11212);
```

and

```
// dev connection
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite://localhost:11211/" + cacheName);
// test connection
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite://localhost:11212/" + cacheName);
```